# cgroups disk IO throttling with zfs

Tags: lxc, zfs, cgroup

I'd like to use `cgroups` with my linux containers to throttle `disk IO` on them. Containers placed on `ZFS` volume `/tank/lxc`. I have three containers each in their own `/tank/lxc/nodeXX` directory.

How can I throttle IO for a container?

Are there minor:major block numbers for ZFS volume/Zpool, how can I find them?

Comment: according to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/cgroups-blkio-weight-doesnt-seem-to-have-the-expected-effect), we should use cfq IO scheduler in order to utilize cgroups IO throttling. So [how to install cfq IO scheduler for ZFS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/577353)?

Comment: The link is broken: https://askubuntu.com/questions/577353/cfq-io-scheduler-for-zfs

Answer (score 1):

It should work, didn't tested it yet.

```
echo 500  > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/lxc/node01/blkio.weight
echo 100  > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/lxc/node02/blkio.weight
echo 1000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/lxc/node04/blkio.weight
```

lxc containers must be up and running, cgroup must be installed.
Regarding to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69300), **cfq disk IO scheduler must be configured** for cgroups in order to be able to throttle the IO. To [configure cfq for ZFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577353):

```
echo cfq > /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_vdev_scheduler
```

To make this parameters persistent, copy the commands to */etc/rc.local*